# dc.js: filter & redraw chart on click

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I rendered a stacked bar and then I'm trying to re-draw the chart with new filter on clicking a button. Now, as I click the button the previous axes remains but the chart disappears and doesn't re-draw. I don't know what I'm missing here..
Here is the JSFiddle for this [stackedBar](https://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/b7woztjw/).

```
function myFunc(){
var dimForHour = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.date; });
    dimForHour.filter([hour, today]);

var dimByChannel = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.channelUUID; });
var groupAvgChan = dimByChannel.group().reduce(
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    p.bytesTxd = p.bytesTxd + v.bytesTxd;
    p.count = p.count + 1;
    p.avg = p.bytesTxd / p.count;
    p.avgTot = p.avgTot + p.avg;
    p.avgPrcnt = (p.avg / p.avgTot) * 100;
    if(p.max < v.bytesTxd) { p.max = v.bytesTxd; }
    p.maxTot = p.maxTot + p.max;
    p.maxPrcnt = (p.max / p.maxTot) * 100;
    return p;
},
function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    p.bytesTxd = p.bytesTxd - v.bytesTxd;
    p.count = p.count - 1;
    p.avg = p.bytesTxd / p.count;
    p.avgTot = p.avgTot - v.avgTot;
    p.avgPrcnt = (p.avg / p.avgTot) * 100;
    if(p.max > v.bytesTxd) { p.max = v.bytesTxd; }
    p.maxTot = p.maxTot - p.max;
    p.maxPrcnt = (p.max / p.maxTot) * 100;
    return p;
},
function reduceInitial() {
    return {
        bytesTxd:0, count:0, avg:0, avgTot:0, 
        avgPrcnt:0, max:0, maxTot:0,maxPrcnt:0};
                                           });
/*chanUtil = dc.barChart("#chanUtil")
                                    chanUtil
                                    .dimension(dimByChannel)
                                    .group(groupAvgChan,"Avg Utilization %").valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.avgPrcnt; })
                                    .stack(groupAvgChan,"Max Utilization %", function(d) { return d.value.maxPrcnt; })
                                    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.channelUUID })))
                                    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);*/

dc.redrawAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to calculate, but the problem seems to arise from this line:

```
    p.avgTot = p.avgTot - v.avgTot;
```

which does not match the corresponding

```
    p.avgTot = p.avgTot + p.avg;
```

`v` does not have a member `avgTot`, so you get `NaN`, and everything breaks from there. The best way to debug these kinds of things is

1. put a breakpoint on the redraw to see what values are in the group
2. put breakpoints inside the reduce functions to see what went wrong in the calculation.

Changing the reduceRemove function to use

```
    p.avgTot = p.avgTot - p.avg;
```

seems to fix the problem (at least, there are still bars after the button is clicked).

Fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0vvh1xex/6/

I also added `elasticY(true)` to be able to see the change better. And yes, the upward transition on bars is particularly wrong here; if you are able to upgrade to dc.js 2.0 (which is on beta 6), that is fixed.

Note: you have some dead code inside `myFunc`: it looks like you are recreating `dimByChannel` and `groupAvgChan` exactly the same, and then not using them for anything.

Comment: NaNs are a common way to end up with an empty chart. Right, you shouldn't need to recreate any dimensions or groups which haven't changed.

Comment: For the same code, when I added filters for `day`,  `week` and `month` it looks like the filters from previous click event are not cleared. I tried using both `filterAll()` and `dispose()` functions with no success.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/qssszL8u/)

Comment: You generally want to avoid creating dimensions and groups in response to events. There are a limited number of dimensions, and each one slows crossfilter down. I'd suggest creating one day/week/month dimension outside the event handler, and then reset it and set it again inside. Having multiple dimensions might explain why you weren't seeing a reset.

Comment: I didn't notice your fiddle when I commented, but this is indeed the problem. You want just one time range filter, and I'd suggest creating it outside the *Filter functions, and clearing and setting it inside them. All dimensions are independent, so you'll get the intersection of the filters the way you have it in that fiddle.